# How can I force Growl notification of the currently playing iTunes track?

Tags: macos, mac, growl

I'd like a hot-key to tell (ask politely) Growl to throw up a notification of what's currently playing in iTunes.

I've poked around a bit but couldn't find an answer "out there."

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer the format that GrowlTunes supplies, you can also create a script that uses it:

```
tell application "GrowlTunes" to show current track
```

Answer (score 3):

My hacked Applescript posted below. This matches the Growl output of iScrobbler. Thanks to The Tentacle for the work! There's information on how to set Quicksilver to launch the script [here](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2007/06/08/hit-and-run-launching-applescripts-with-keyboard-shortcuts.html?page=4).

```
tell application "GrowlHelperApp"
-- Make a list of all the notification types
-- that this script will ever send:
set the allNotificationsList to {"iTunes Playing Track"}
-- Make a list of the notifications
-- that will be enabled by default.
-- Those not enabled by default can be enabled later
-- in the 'Applications' tab of the growl prefpane.
set the enabledNotificationsList to {"iTunes Playing Track"}
-- Register our script with growl.
-- You can optionally (as here) set a default icon
-- for this scripts notifications.
register as application "Growl iTunes Notification" all notifications allNotificationsList default notifications enabledNotificationsList icon of application "iTunes"

set title_text to "Null"
set body_text to ""
set body_temp to ""
set has_artwork to false

tell application "iTunes"
    if player state is playing then
        set trck to current track

        if artworks of trck is not {} then
            get artwork 1 of trck
            set pic to data of result
            set has_artwork to true
        end if

        set title_text to "Now Playing"

        get name of trck
        set body_text to "Track: " & result

        get rating of trck
        set rate to result / 20

        repeat rate times
            set body_temp to body_temp & "★"
        end repeat

        if rate is less than 5 then
            repeat (5 - rate) times
                set body_temp to body_temp & "☆"
            end repeat
        end if

        set body_text to body_text & " (" & body_temp & ")" & return

        get album of trck
        set body_text to body_text & "Album: " & result & return

        get artist of trck
        set body_text to body_text & "Artist: " & result

    end if
end tell

if has_artwork then
    notify with name "iTunes Playing Track" title title_text description body_text application name "Growl iTunes Notification" pictImage the pic
else
    notify with name "iTunes Playing Track" title title_text description body_text application name "Growl iTunes Notification" image from location "file:///Users/drewbeck/Library/Scripts/Custom/no_album.tiff"
end if
```

end tell

Comment: Don't forget that last "end tell." It ended up outside the code box for some reason?!

Comment: You should be able to edit your post to get that last staement in the code block? Anyway, glad it helped...

Answer (score 2):

You need a plugin for iTunes. [Here it is.](http://growl.info/documentation/growltunes.php)

Comment: GrowlTunes works for getting notifications (as does iScrobbler, which I use), but I it doesn't seem to be able to let me tell it explicitly to show a notification when I want, only on "Changed Tracks" or "Started Playing."

So how can I explicitly poll iTunes (with GrowlTunes, iScrobbler, or another application) for What's Playing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an applescript for this (don't remember where I got this) -- I compile this to an application triggered by Quicksilver, to get immediate notification of what is playing when I want, keeping iTunes minimised at all times:

[image: growl]

```
 tell application "GrowlHelperApp"
    -- Make a list of all the notification types
    -- that this script will ever send:
    set the allNotificationsList to {"iTunes Playing Track"}
    -- Make a list of the notifications
    -- that will be enabled by default.
    -- Those not enabled by default can be enabled later
    -- in the 'Applications' tab of the growl prefpane.
    set the enabledNotificationsList to {"iTunes Playing Track"}
    -- Register our script with growl.
    -- You can optionally (as here) set a default icon
    -- for this scripts notifications.
    register as application "Growl iTunes Notification" all notifications allNotificationsList default notifications enabledNotificationsList icon of application "iTunes"

    set title_text to "Nothing playing"
    set body_text to ""
    set has_artwork to false

    tell application "iTunes"
        if player state is playing then
            set trck to current track

            if artworks of trck is not {} then
                get artwork 1 of trck
                set pic to data of result
                set has_artwork to true
            end if

            get name of trck
            set title_text to result

            get time of trck
            set title_time to result
            set body_text to title_time & " =["

            get rating of trck
            set rate to result / 20

            repeat rate times
                set body_text to body_text & " ❤ "

            end repeat

            get artist of trck
            set body_text to body_text & "]   ❧ " & result

            get album of trck
            set body_text to body_text & " ⇒ " & result

        end if
    end tell

    if has_artwork then
        notify with name "iTunes Playing Track" title title_text description body_text application name "Growl iTunes Notification" pictImage the pic
    else
        notify with name "iTunes Playing Track" title title_text description body_text application name "Growl iTunes Notification"
        "iTunesLibraryPlaylistIcon.icns"
    end if

end tell
```

Comment: Beautiful. I hacked it a bit to make the output look like the iScrobbler output. Code posted below. Much <3!